# uTorrent keeps crashing (after upgrade to Mavericks)

Tags: macos, crash

I've been using uTorrent for more than a year. But since I've upgraded to OS X 10.9, uTorrent (now version 1.8.4) keeps crashing: sometimes it works for maybe couple of hours, sometimes for about 15 minutes — and then just disappears (without displaying crash reporter or anything).

Example search for "torrent" in Console.app:

```
11/29/13 5:12:33.569 PM uTorrent[29203]: XPC error messaging com.apple.IconServicesAgent: Connection interrupted
11/29/13 5:12:33.569 PM uTorrent[29203]: XPC error messaging com.apple.IconServicesAgent: Connection invalid
11/29/13 5:26:33.990 PM uTorrent[29203]: uTorrent(29203,0xa081c1a8) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3) *** error: can't allocate region *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
11/29/13 5:26:47.186 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[177]: (com.bittorrent.uTorrent.41744[29203]) Exited with code: 1
// crash @ 5:26, (manual) restart @ 5:50 PM and crash again @ 6:16 --G.M.
11/29/13 5:50:38.483 PM WindowServer[96]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "µTorrent" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
11/29/13 5:50:38.797 PM uTorrent[29519]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
11/29/13 5:50:38.797 PM uTorrent[29519]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
11/29/13 5:50:40.450 PM WindowServer[96]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "µTorrent" after 2.97 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
11/29/13 6:16:58.007 PM uTorrent[29519]: uTorrent(29519,0xa081c1a8) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3) *** error: can't allocate region *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
11/29/13 6:16:59.226 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[177]: (com.bittorrent.uTorrent.41744[29519]) Exited with code: 1
```

I've tried to google something either about uTorrent and Mavericks in general, or about uTorrent and errors from this log — to no avail.

Does anybody else have this problem? Any advice?

**Upd.** Following advice from answers I've tried upgrading to uTorrent beta 1.9.1. It *seems* to be slightly more stable but the problem persists:

```
11/30/13 11:15:53.540 PM uTorrent[3250]: uTorrent(3250,0xa081c1a8) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3) *** error: can't allocate region *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
11/30/13 11:15:53.541 PM uTorrent[3250]: uTorrent(3250,0xa081c1a8) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3) *** error: can't allocate region *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
11/30/13 11:15:54.434 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[178]: (com.bittorrent.uTorrent.41744[3250]) Exited with code: 1
```

P.S. Warning: **uTorrent beta 1.9.1 corrupted** some of my **files** (instead of `something.avi` I now have `something.avi` and `something.avi.1` — in different folders and neither of them is playable). I can't recommend this 'upgrade', to say the least.

It's time to try some other client, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The 1.8 version of uTorrent isn't updated for Mountain Lion notifications and the malloc errors you posted indicate a fairly severe memory management problem. Unless an update past 1.8.4 gets released, you might try running the 1.9 beta version as it has memory leak corrections listed in the release notes.

It contemplates newer OS explicitly and the fix for this error might arrive there first or exclusively.

http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/mac

Comment: I have version 1.8.4 — latest stable version released  01.11.2013

Comment: Oops - I somehow thought you had 1.8.3 so I'll edit my answer

Comment: (but maybe I should try beta 1.9, indeed; thanks)

Comment: Another alternative would be to use http://www.transmissionbt.com instead of µTorrent. It is small, fast, free and open-source ;) Do have a look if you have the opportunity.

Comment: From a [uTorrent forum](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?pid=710028#p710028) for Mac beta releases: `urbanracer34 wrote:
Does this build fix the Inactive memory leak?

vadimt (Moderator) responded: Hi,
Inactive memory leak will be fixed in the next versions.
Thanks!` The "next versions" referred to are after 1.9.1

Answer (score -1):

You could add Vuze to the alternative list. It is also free and allows use of a proxy server.